# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :url=>""}, missing required keys: [:url]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a bit new to rails. so I'm tryna do a craigslist clone. so far I have implemented all the categories and the subcategories. I came upon this error when I attempted to SEO my url links so that it could be like this craigslist-clone/c/community/activities/3 where 'community' is the parent category and 'activities' being the subcategory and therefore '3' being the post at which.

now I can click on each parent category error-less. the only time I get an error is when I click on a subcategory and the error is as follows:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :url=>""}, missing required keys: [:url]

  <% category.subcategories.limit(10).each do |subcategory| %>
               <div class= "subcat"><%= link_to subcategory.name, show_category_path(subcategory.url) %></div>
           <%end%> 

           </div>
```

My categories_controller :

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
    category_ids = @category.subcategories.ids
    category_ids << @category.id
    @posts = Post.where(category_id: category_ids)

  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find_by_url(params[:url])
    end


    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def category_params
      params.fetch(:category, {})
    end
end
```

My home.html.erb is :

```
            <div class="row">
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <div class="col-4 mb-4 category-box">
            <p class="h6"><strong><%= link_to category.name, show_category_path(category.url), class: "text-dark" %></strong></p>

            <% category.subcategories.limit(10).each do |subcategory| %>
                <div class= "subcat"><%= link_to subcategory.name, show_category_path(subcategory.url) %></div>
            <%end%> 

            </div>
            <% end %>
```

routes.rb

````
  devise_for :accounts
  resources :posts
  resources :categories, except:[:show]
  get "c/:url" => "categories#show", as: :show_category
  post "message/send" => "public#send_enquiry_to_user", as: :send_enquiry
  get "/scams" => "public#scams", as: :scams
  get "/terms" => "public#terms", as: :terms
  get "/safety" => "public#safety", as: :safety
  get "/faqs" => "public#faqs", as: :faqs
   devise_scope :account do
     get "/accounts/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
   end
  root to: "public#home"
end```
````

my category.rb Model :

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent, class_name:"Category", optional: true
    has_many :subcategories, class_name:"Category", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :posts
end
```

my Categories table :

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "url"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "parent_id"
  end
```

I just feel like I've reached a dead end, any help or any recommendation of a resource I may need to read to be able to overcome this problem is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a custom route like this:

```
get "c/:url" => "categories#show", as: :show_category
```

Therefore you need to explicitly pass a `url` key to the route method, like this:

```
show_category_path(url: category.url)
```

You could also, alternatively, [override the named route parameter](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) instead of using a [bound parameter](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters). In other words, you could define the route using something like this:

```
resources :categories, path: "c", only: :show, param: :url
```

This generates the following route, and your original code would work fine with it:

```
category GET     /c/:url(.:format)    categories#show
```

Comment: so I explicitly passed the url key to the route method, but I still cannot seem to click error-less on any of the subcategories. I get striked by an error saying `no route matches [GET] "/c"` I want my url to be like this when I click on a subcategory: '/community/activities/3' do I need to generate a new route ?

Comment: @HaithamMaryan Are you getting the error because your `subcategory.url == nil`? You've shared neither your code nor your data, so I'm really just guessing what could be the error.

Comment: If you want a different route (potentially with different behaviour?) for subcategory URLs then yes, you'll need to define this as a separate route in `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

One of you `subcategory` seems to be having a blank URL.

```
<% category.subcategories.limit(10).each do |subcategory| %>
  <% next if subcategory.url.blank? %>
  <div class= "subcat"><%= link_to subcategory.name, show_category_path(subcategory.url) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: now after I pasted this block of code, I can't seem to see any subcategories in my homepage. I only see the parent categories @ErvalhouS

Comment: I have attached categoryModel and category Table in my question

Answer (score 0):

So i have also run into this kind of problem before and you may want to change your `resource` route with a `:path` option and it might help.

```
devise_for :accounts
  resources :posts
  resources :categories, path: "c", except:[:show] do
   get "/:url" => "categories#show", as: :show_category
  end

  post "message/send" => "public#send_enquiry_to_user", as: :send_enquiry
  get "/scams" => "public#scams", as: :scams
  get "/terms" => "public#terms", as: :terms
  get "/safety" => "public#safety", as: :safety
  get "/faqs" => "public#faqs", as: :faqs
   devise_scope :account do
     get "/accounts/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
   end
  root to: "public#home"
end
```

or you could also just pass explicitly pass the `:url` to your route helper like `show_category_path(url: category.url)`